# Не удается отправить PUSH уведомление

Tags: javascript, php

```
$ch = curl_init('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, ['Content-Type:application/json', 'Authorization:key=253*******92']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ["to"   => 'cKZHw****Z6s:APA91bGTJ8AO91xP8V7VjV*********************************IdoigREyYPZnFNfGEl6GMK0nd1Qyslbil47VMREdefI3SCEUdJHwAEF26jFRXYPgdGBMxLOucJ51CI-ud1', 
                                      "data" => ["title" =>  "Portugal vs. Denmark",
                                                 "text"  =>  "5 to 1"]]);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Id пользователя получаю, все есть. Но при попытке отправить curl запрос(POST). Для передачи сообщения пользователю. Получаю сообщение

**https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/**

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 0
Date: Sun, 07 Mar 2021 01:04:32 GMT
Content-Length: 135
Alt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Connection: close

A valid push subscription endpoint should be specified in the URL as such: https://fcm.googleapis.com/wp/dHIoDxE7Hdg:APA91bH1Zj0kNa...
```

**https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send**

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 07 Mar 2021 01:06:10 GMT
Expires: Sun, 07 Mar 2021 01:06:10 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Error=DeprecatedEndpoint1
```

В первом случаи 404 ошибка, во втором 301. Что не так выполняю?

Способ получения id подписки

```
function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
    let rawData = window.atob((base64String + '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4)).replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/')),
        outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) 
        outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);   
    return outputArray;
}
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(() => {return navigator.serviceWorker.ready;}).then(reg => reg.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly: true, applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array('BAVR1KZoitVgsfJ8ICyp4XE0H4riw8SRIjr26F4TqM7HUrl5f3clkOMLNu_xZkQB__eJ7f_GRmpdC--BZjqmzcA')}).then(sub => {
    console.log(sub.endpoint);              
}
));
```

sub.endpoint = https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/f-dlS9a_QLk:APA91bEkp83uEx3Y3Tj-_myhkbo7Vyo9RTpN1DtuKGBOPWTBixiuUA0UR_2GXw5t4VY0BH9WmNOycONcQzv_6Rbsx8XRbeFXzYCYe-sQOqYrBWkaH_eoMoRxhYyKtWkpAsUF7vquHrz

Как я понял, необходимо брать

```
f-dlS9a_QLk:APA91bEkp83uEx3Y3Tj-_myhkbo7Vyo9RTpN1DtuKGBOPWTBixiuUA0UR_2GXw5t4VY0BH9WmNOycONcQzv_6Rbsx8XRbeFXzYCYe-sQOqYrBWkaH_eoMoRxhYyKtWkpAsUF7vquHrz
```

это и будет ключ подписки пользователя.

Comment: Не проще использовать [sdk](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cloud-messaging.html)? Судя по ошибкам вы endpoint не правильно определяете. И, не лучше ли [перейти на http v1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1)?

Comment: Добавил код того как получаю токен пользователя. Сейчас весь гугл облазал. Не могу найти пример того как получить токен на http v1.

Comment: хз, если заголовок application/json, то джейсоном и надо подавать данные пост-запросу, а не массивом. Отключи CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER

Answer (score 1):

не в качестве ответа, но мб поможет. у меня такой код отправки вэб-пуша используется для FCM

```
protected function send($data, $tokens, &$code){
    $API_URL    = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    $SERVER_KEY = ".......";

    $tz   = new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow');
    $now  = new \DateTime('now', $tz);
    $stop =(new \DateTime('now', $tz))->setTime(23,0,0);



    $defaults = [
        'registration_ids' => $tokens,
        'notification' => [
            'icon'         => "https://exaple.com/img/notify.png",
            'click_action' => "https://example.com"
        ],
        'time_to_live' => $stop->getTimestamp() - $now->getTimestamp()
    ];

    $data = array_replace_recursive($defaults, $data);

    $body = json_encode($data);

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: key=' . $SERVER_KEY,
        'Content-length: ' . strlen($body),
    ];


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if(!$code){
        $err     = curl_error($ch);
        $errCode = curl_errno($ch);
        $this->_io->out("err: #$errCode, $err");
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $code == 200 ? json_decode($response, true) : $response;
}
```

Comment: а курл заголовок Content-length сам не устанавливает?))